# Pandas applied function erasing data

Tags: python, pandas

```
In  [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[pubA, linkA,None], [pubB, linkB,textB], [pubC, linkC,textC]], columns=['pub', 'link','text])

In  [2]: df
Out [2]: 
    pub   link   text
 0  pubA  linkA  None
 1  pubB  linkB  textB
 2  pubC  linkC  textC
```

I have code I'm using to pull text from the web. My function iterates through the `df` and checks the content of `'text'` to make sure it is empty first. If `'text'` already has content it will `pass`. If `'text'` is empty it checks  `'pub'` to see if I've got an appropriate BeautifulSoup template for that publication and if so returns clean text. If there is not yet a template the function will `pass`.

```
def pull_text(row):
    try:
        if(pd.isnull(row['text'])):
            if row['publication' ] == 'PubA':
                print('Now serving row',row.name,'of',len(df),'Template:',row['publication'])
                sys.stdout.flush()

                #Do Template A
                time.sleep(rand)
                return article.strip()

            elif row['publication' ] == 'PubB':
                #Do Template B
                time.sleep(rand)
                return article.strip()

            elif row['publication' ] == 'PubC':
                # Do Template C
                rand = randint(2,10)
                print('Waiting', rand, 'seconds')
                sys.stdout.flush()

                time.sleep(rand)
                return result.strip()
            else:
                pass
                print('No template set for', row['publication'],':row', row.name)
        else:
            pass
    except AttributeError:
        print('error at',row.name)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        return 'error'

df['text'] = df.apply (lambda row: pull_text (row),axis=1)
```

Each template works fine and has pulled text from each publication. However whenever I run the function (such as after adding a new template) it seems to erase all pre-existing text data and fills in the pre-existing blanks (where it can).

```
In  [3] df['text'] = df.apply (lambda row: pull_text (row),axis=1)
In  [4] df
Out [4] pub   link   text
     0  pubA  linkA  textA
     1  pubB  linkB  None
     2  pubC  linkC  None
```

Whilst what I desire is

```
Out [4] pub   link   text
     0  pubA  linkA  textA
     1  pubB  linkB  textB
     2  pubC  linkC  textC
```

All I can think of is that I am somehow setting the value of `'text'` as a null value if it is not already, but I'm not sure how I'm doing it.

Comment: You know you could simply write `df.apply(pull_text, axis=1)`. No need for a lambda function here.

Comment: ...why do I have a Lambda there? Thanks! I'm so used to iterating over the rows in other functions I think of everything in loops.

Comment: I took the Lambda out as you suggested and whereas before I believe the function worked fine, now it is rewriting every `text` cell even if I had already collected that text.

Comment: Update: I took out BOTH `else:pass` lines, tried it as a straightforward `.apply` and now it seems to be functioning fine. I stand corrected, you stand (still) correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is going on is that `pass` makes your function return `None`.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks! There is the simple answer I just couldn't see. I was thinking of the whole thing as a loop rather than as applying a function so thought I needed the `pass` if the null check was False. Didn't realise `pass` would return something, thought it would just move along to the next iteration, but clearly I'm not actually iterating.Just pulled out the `else:pass` entirely and it works fine.

Comment: @JamesAllen-Robertson I'm glad I could help. Functions in Python *always* return *something* (unless execution is interrupted by an exception). BTW - I checked out your profile and I noticed you are a media theorist interested in NLP. If you ever need an extra set of eyes on some problem or want to talk topic modelling, language models, etc, drop me a line at my stackoverflow username at g-mail. Also, if this solved your issue, I'd appreciate the accept :)